# How can I access user's data from an identity credential provided by a Cognito identity pool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have the following scenario:

1 - A Web Client App authenticates an user throught a Cognito User pool

2 - A Web Client App retrieves a credentials provided by the Cognito Identity Pool (STS temporary credentials, not the id token or acess token)

3 - Web Client App sends the above credentials to the API Gateway which is set to use AWS_IAM as Authorization method

4 - The API Gateway invokes a lambda function which need to know who is the user associated to the credentials: user id or username

**The problem**

How retrieve the user's data from a credential provided by the Cognito Identity Pool in the API Gateway or in the lambda function?

My first idea was to send the id token in a additional HTTP header to the API Gateway, but I didn't find a way to decode the token in API Gateway.

The second alternative was the id token pass through to the function lambda that [would decode the token](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/tree/master/Cognito/decode-verify-jwt), but I think it would be an heaveweight operation to a lambda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [map identity id to user pool id](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/mapping-cognito-identity-id-and-user-pool-id.html) first if you are using user pool as an authentication provider for cognito identity pool. Then to retrieve the user's data, you can use [AdminGetUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html) in your lambda function.